# Convincing poetry to exclude files from the build

Tags: python-packaging, python-poetry

I'm using poetry to build my package. I configure pyproject.toml to include all the files in `tests` but want to exclude `tests\not_this_dir`. The goal is that as I add additional stuff under `tests` they are picked up automatically. Because I have some tests that use proprietary data sets, I put those in `tests\not_this_dir` so they are not distributed.

The issue I'm having is that I can't convince poetry to exclude `not_this_dir`. Here's the content of my abbreviated `pyproject.toml`.

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "mypkg"
version = "0.2.0"
include = [
    { path = "data" },
    { path = "tests" },

exclude = [
    { path = "tests/not_this_dir" }
]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

The file structure is:

```
mypkg
¦   .gitignore
¦   pyproject.toml
¦   README.txt
¦       
+---mypkg
¦   ¦   a.py
¦   ¦   b.py
¦   ¦   __init__.py
¦           
+---data
¦       e.json
¦       f.json
¦       
+---tests
¦   ¦   conftest.py
¦   ¦   test_g.py
¦   ¦   test_h.py
¦   ¦   __init__.py
¦   ¦               
¦   +---data
¦   ¦   +---g
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   otherfile.txt
¦   ¦   ¦               
¦   ¦   +---h
¦   ¦       ¦   differentfile.txt
¦   +---not_this_dir
¦   ¦   +---g
¦   ¦   ¦   ¦   otherfile2.txt
¦   ¦   ¦               
¦   ¦   +---h
¦   ¦       ¦   differentfile2.txt
```

When I run `poetry build` it's including `not_this_dir`. The files in `not_this_dir` are in git, so I don't want to add them to `.gitignore`. The only thing that seems to work is to completely give up on the use of `exclude` and configure `pyproject.toml` like this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "mypkg"
version = "0.2.0"
include = [
    { path = "data" },
    { path = "tests/*.py" },
    { path = "tests/data" },

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

so that it only explicitly includes the files I want, rather than explicitly excluding them. I've tried various exclude glob variants such as `tests/**/not_this_dir`, `tests/not_this_dir/*` and nothing seems to work. The poetry documentation at https://python-poetry.org/docs/1.1/pyproject/ is super vague on the interaction between include and exclude and what the allowed file glob syntax is. It seems like include overrides exclude, or exclude is just being ignored?

Answer (score 6):

I finally got a tip from this issue https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1597. What will make this work is to NOT use the `path =`  syntax in the exclude section. You need to change

```
exclude = [
    { path = "tests/not_this_dir" }
]
```

to

```
exclude = [
    "tests/not_this_dir"
]
```

Then it will exclude `not_this_dir` as expected.